# Rails params[:email] always returning nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following simple rails page:

```
<h1> New User </h1>

<%= form_for :user, url:users_path do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :email %>
    <%= f.text_field :email %>  
</p>

<p>
    <%= f.label :password %>
    <%= f.text_field :password %>
</p>

<%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

The create action gets executed and I want to access the :email attribute.

```
  def create 
    render text: params[:email].inspect
  end
```

The above always displays nil.

Comment: Inspect `params[:user][:email]`

Comment: Is'nt there a shortcut method. That seems long when I am passing email to a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`form_for :user` will place all parameters beneath a `:user` key

```
render text: params[:user][:email].inspect
```

Comment: So this looks good user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email]) Is there a nicer way!